# How to Change the Colour of a JLabel and JButton

Tags: java, colors, jbutton, jlabel

I just changed the background colour of my frame using:

```
panel1.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
```

Now, it would probably look better if the text and the buttons are changed. How can I change the **`JLabel`** and the **`JButtons`** a bit more brighter? It will be much better when it is white because right now it looks like this:

[image: Wall game]

Imagine *that!*

Comment: I believe it's *button.setBackground(Color.red);*
*button.setOpaque(true);*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to Change the Colour of a JLabel and JButton

To change the ***background color*** of JLabel and JButton, you can do this:

```
JButton btn = new JButton();
btn.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

JLabel lbl= new JLabel ();
lbl.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
lbl.setOpaque(true);    //If opaque property is false, you can't see the color
```

To change the ***text color*** of JLabel and JButton, you can do this:

```
btn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
lbl.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a specific HEX colour? I want it to be `#E6E6FA` I actually found it creepy just plain white.

Comment: @MCGuy From the Color class, they have a constructor which allows use to set the color based on RGB values. For example `setBackgound(new Color(100, 125, 150));` If you want to use HEX values, you can consider using `Color.decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton button = new JButton("test");//sample JButton
button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);//Set background color
button.setOpaque(true);//needs to be true in order to show color

JLabel title = new JLabel("I love stackoverflow!", JLabel.CENTER);

title.setForeground(Color.white);//simply set color
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Currently, your answer is flagged "low quality" and might get removed.